# What is the recommended way to use MongoDB with a NodeJS application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently building a web app which needs a database to store user info. The startup I'm working for wants to deploy it on Elastic Beanstalk. I am just getting started with all the cloud stuff and am completely at a loss.

Should I create a MongoDB Atlas cluster? Will it be able to connect to my app hosted on EB? Will I need to upgrade my plan on AWS to be able to connect to a database? Can it be integrated with DynamoDB? If yes, is DynamoDB significantly costlier?

I don't have answers to any of the above questions and am just honestly looking for a roadmap on what to do. I went through numerous articles and videos but still can't arrive at a solution. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create a MongoDB Atlas cluster?

That is one possible solution. You could also look at [Amazon's Document DB service](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/), which is MongoDB compatible.

> Will it be able to connect to my app hosted on EB?

There is nothing preventing you from connecting to a MongoDB Atlas cluster from EB.

> Will I need to upgrade my plan on AWS to be able to connect to a
> database?

No

> Can it be integrated with DynamoDB?

DynamoDB is a completely different database system, that shares almost nothing in common with MongoDB other than the fact that neither of them use SQL. If your application already uses MongoDB, then converting it to DynamoDB could be a large lift.

> If yes, is DynamoDB significantly costlier?

In general, DynamoDB would be significantly cheaper than MongoDB, because DynamoDB is a "serverless" offering that charges based on your usage patterns, while MongoDB would include charges for a server running 24/7.